# the quasi-isomorphisms are homotopic-equivalence for DGAS

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras

I just want to know more explainations on this result. So, please let me know where I can find the original paper on this result. THANKS

Comment: Might I suggest http://mathoverflow.net/howtoask?

Comment: I believe this goes back to Daniel Quillen's 1970 paper "On the (co-)homology of commutative rings." * Applications of Categorical Algebra*; however do read the FAQ of this site.